Virtual Box Python Core / Win 32 API issue
I installed Virtual Box and during the installation I received a warning about missing dependencies.
I installed the dependencies (Python Core and Win 32 API) using the pip install pywin32 command.
Every time I try to start a machine I now get this error message:

supHardenedWinVerifyProcess failed with
(rc=-5637)
Please try reinstalling VirtualBox.
where: supR3HardNtChildPurify what: 5
(-5637)
Process Verification
Failure: Error query virtual memory information.


I tried to install Python Core and Win 32 to solve the problem, as that is what VirtualBox said the dependencies were, and I used the pip install pywin32 command, after having installed Python both from the Web and the Microsoft Store. I expected this would solve the problem, and it does not appear to have.
I tried creating other devices with varying CPU, Memory and Storage configurations. I expected this could be a problem, but the error has not changed.


Following instructions on this website helped me with a similar issue
However, I found it necessary to first uninstall all Python and Virtualbox software and start from a clean slate.
These steps worked for me:

Using Windows System Settings, uninstall Python and Oracle Virtualbox.  Restart system.
Visit https://www.python.org/downloads/ to download install the latest version of Python using Admin Privileges, and select the box to Add python.exe to PATH.
Run the PowerShell/CMD as admin, and type “py -m pip install pywin32” to install pywin32.  Restart system.
Visit https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads to download and install the latest version of Virtualbox using Admin Privileges.

From there, any previous VMs created still appear and all should work fine.

While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - From Review
